# F#: Trying to support passing a function in a constructor in both F# and C# idioms

Tags: c#, constructor, f#, overloading

My type:

```ml
open System

type MyType (myFn : unit -> bool) =
    member this.MyResult with get () = myFn ()
    new (myFn : Func<bool>) = MyType (myFn.Invoke)
```

The error that I get:

`A unique overload for method 'MyType' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: new : myFn:(unit -> bool) -> MyType, new : myFn:Func<bool> -> MyType`

Since I've already provided the type annotations, what's the real reason this doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

F# will be able to call the constructor if it takes the `Func<bool>` delegate. So, going with a single overload that takes `Func<bool>` should work for both C# and F#:

```
open System

type MyType (myFn : Func<bool>) =
  member this.MyResult with get () = myFn.Invoke ()
```